# Is there a key command to shift Apple Mail focus to top?

Tags: mail.app, email

This one drives me crazy...

If you search in Apple Mail, you likely end up way back in time in your list of emails. When I am ready to read new email I have to scroll, scroll, scroll to the top of the list again.

There HAS to be a key command or something I am missing to instantly jump to the top of the list.

Is there?

Comment: What about on an iPad? This one drives me crazy... If you search in Apple Mail, you likely end up way back in time in your list of emails. When I am ready to read new email I have to scroll, scroll, scroll to the top of the list again. There HAS to be a key command or something I am missing to instantly jump to the top of the list. Is there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to press the <kbd>Home</kbd> key (<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>← left arrow key</kbd> on a laptop) to go to the top.

Alternatively, if you have a multi touch trackpad, you can use [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/) to set a gesture for <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd>. I personally think this is the best way, and I set a three fingered swipe down to <kbd>Home</kbd> and a three fingered swipe up to <kbd>End</kbd>

[image: BTT three fingered swipe home and end]

Answer (score 4):

On my MacBook Pro: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Opt</kbd>-<kbd>↑</kbd> to go to top of messages list. Drove me nuts till I found it.

Comment: Only Ctrl-Opt-↑ worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

On an iOS device tapping the top of the screen where the time is displayed will scroll a window back to the top instantly. Works in Mail, Safari, Messages, Settings, Contacts- everything I tried it on except for the Readerware Books app.